# В чем проблема моей попытки перевода кода с java на rust?

Tags: java, сервер, rust, udp, minecraft

Я пытаюсь сделать "рукопожатие" с майнкрафт сервером на Rust. Я основываюсь на [этом](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30768091/java-sending-handshake-packets-to-minecraft-server) ответе и [этом](https://wiki.vg/Protocol) вики.

Код из ответа на java работает, однако любые запросы, посылаемые на сервер через UDPSocket на Rust выдают ошибку "Удаленный хост принудительно разорвал существующее подключение. (os error 10054)".

Для примера:
Я запустил майнкрафт и открыл мир для локальной сети. Адрес сервера - 127.0.0.1:50312 (порт может меняться). Запросы с java работают, однако такой код в Rust (простая попытка пинга):

```
let mut socket = UdpSocket::bind("127.0.0.1:50001").expect("Failed to connect");

let address = "127.0.0.1";
let port: u16 = 50312;

let addr = format!("{}:{}", address, port);
let mut data = [0u8; 2];
data[0] = 0x01;
socket.send_to(&data, addr.clone());
```

Выдает вышеупомянутую ошибку при последующем прослушивании сокета

[Вот](https://yadi.sk/d/6jBT8wBschrXTQ) полный незаконченный код моих запросов (код экспериментальный)

Вопрос: Что я делаю не так? Как правильно это сделать?

Comment: Maxgmer, спасибо. Достаточно было обращаться не через UDP, а через TCP. Все остальное я сделал верно, спасибо

Comment: отлично! Я тогда удалю свой коммент с ответом и напишу его в нормальный ответ, если не против.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C первого взгляда сразу заметно, что разные протоколы.
В примере на Java используется класс `Socket`, который использует под капотом TCP/IP протокол. В Rust примере выше используется `UdpSocket`, который использует другой протокол - UDP/IP.

В Java UDP/IP сокет называется DatagramSocket.

Нужно просто сменить `UdpSocket` на другой, который работает по протоколу TCP/IP.